# How can I launch an Automator application using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

I am trying to use [Remote Buddy](http://www.iospirit.com/products/remotebuddy/) to control Photo Booth, but I need a way to switch between Still and Video modes, my solution to this was to use an Automator app to select one or other of the two radio buttons when a remote button is pressed.

I've created the .app, and it works fine when I double click it from the desktop, but I need a way to launch the .app from within Remote Buddy, and AppleScript seems to be my only option.

tl;dr

I need to be able to launch an Automator .app file using AppleScript, but can't figure out the correct syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I made an Automator app named `Untitled` I would start it by using this command `tell application "Untitled" to activate`

Once you create an application using one of the following methods, that application can be accessed in any other script via its name. It's defined globally, as is any other application on your mac. Just use the `tell application "app Name"`

Two ways of creating an application :
[image: Using AppleScript]
[image: Using automator]

Comment: Are app names global? Do I need to navigate to a certain directory first, or will it work from anywhere?

Answer (score 3):

```
activate app ((system attribute "HOME") & "/Desktop/test.app/")
```

---

You could also use the `automator` shell command.

```
automator test.workflow
automator test.app
automator test.workflow -v # verbose
automator -i lol test.workflow
echo lol | automator -i - test.workflow
automator -i $'lol\nlol2' test.workflow # \n separates input strings
automator -d somevar=somevalue test.workflow
```

Answer (score 0):

You would first name your automator app for example "photobooth.app" then you would go in applescript an type in

```
tell application "photobooth.app"
activate
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it directly with Automator scripting. This does not access the app, but rather the workflow. It is advantageous, because you can edit the settings/contents of some of the individual workflow items.

I suppose my answer would be better suited for the question:

### How can I launch an Automator *Workflows* using AppleScript?

I find that saving the Automator action first avoids problems. e.g.

```
set theWorkflowName to "Merge PDF Files"
set myWorkflow to make new workflow with properties {name:theWorkflowName, path:POSIX path of ((path to temporary items as string) & theWorkflowName & ".workflow" as string)}
set myWorkflow to open POSIX path of ((path to temporary items as string) & theWorkflowName & ".workflow" as string)
```

---

## Merge PDF Files Droplet

```
on open the_Droppings
-- CONVERT INPUT LIST OF ALIASES TO POSIX PATHS
repeat with itemStep from 1 to count of the_Droppings
    set item itemStep of the_Droppings to POSIX path of item itemStep of the_Droppings
end repeat

tell application "Automator"
    activate
    set myWorkflow to open POSIX file "/Users/USERNAME/Dropbox/Scripts/Automator/Workflows/merge PDF files.workflow"
    set actionsList to name of Automator action of myWorkflow
    set firstAction to item 1 of actionsList
    tell myWorkflow
        (*
        get index of Automator action firstAction
        get input types of Automator action firstAction
        get path of Automator action firstAction
        get path of Automator action firstAction
        get value of setting of Automator action firstAction
        *)
        set value of setting of Automator action firstAction to the_Droppings -- MUST BE LIST OF POSIX PATHS
    end tell
end tell
end open
```